# Using a MaskFormatter to restrict a JFormattedTextField to 2 OR 3 integers?

Tags: maskedtextbox, jformattedtextfield

I am currently using a MaskFormatter to limit my JFormattedTextFields to two integers like so:

textField = new JFormattedTextField(createFormatter("##"));

but what should I do if I want the text field to accept two OR three integers 
this is how I'm thinking of it logically in my head: [ ("##") || ("###") ]